# Why is Scala confused about the return data type?

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala code:

```
def isOpen(c: Char, openC: List[Char]) = {
  if(c == '(') openC :+ '(';
  else if(c == ')') openC.reverse.tail.reverse;
}
```

This is trying to append an item to `openC` List if the conditions is met, and in the case it isn't, it's trying to take all the items in the `openC` except for the last one added. The issue I can't understand how to solve is that Scala is interpreting this function to return an `Any` type, when I would like is a `List[Char]`. I tried re-writing this with a `ListBuffer[Char]` type too. I'm trying to do his in a funcitonal programming manner, without relying on `val` declarations.

A similar question has been answered in this forum before by stating that it's due to the fact that Scala gets "confused" when using if-else statement that have further actions after they get executed. But I'm not sure how this applies here. I'm still trying to understand how this works.

Comment: the `else` part is missing

Comment: BTW, it is a best practice to use explicit return types. Specially for public methods, it helps the compiler, it produces better error messages and it helps you catch bugs more quickly.

Comment: `openC.reverse.tail.reverse` === `openc.init` Also, it's better to deal with `List` s in reverse: then you could do `'(' :: openC` and `openC.tail` for your two cases, which are both constant time as opposed to linear as you have it now. And then, you would just `reverse` the final result once in the end after you are done with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `if` expression has type `Any` because

- if c is `(`, it's a `List[Char]`
- if c is `)`, it's a `List[Char]`
- otherwise, no branch of the `if` applies, so that's a `Unit`

The least upper bound of `Unit` and `List[Char]` is `Any`, thus that's the result type of the `if`.

If you want the result type to be `List[Char]`, you'll have to add an `else` clause to catch the cases that weren't handled by the earlier `if`/`else if`s which results in a `List[Char]`.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing else statement. In case, you will not give else statement it will assume Any as return type

```
def isOpen(c: Char, openC: List[Char]) = {
  if(c == '(') openC :+ '('
  else if(c == ')') openC.reverse.tail.reverse
  else openC.reverse.tail.reverse
}
```